# Reactive Kafka Consumer Back Pressure - Configure the value at which back pressure is applied

Tags: reactor-kafka

So with the reactive kafka consumer, back pressure will be applied once your consumer has a certain number of messages in flight. At this point it automatically stops fetching new messages from kafka. I think the value defaults to 258.

Is there any configuration value that can be used to alter the number of in flight messages the consumer has before it applies back pressure?